# Parametrization of context-sensitive language in polynomial time

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, fl.formal-languages

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet. Let $L\subset \Sigma^*$ be a context-sensitive language containing a word of every length.

Can we always find $f:\Sigma^*\to L$ computable in polynomial time in length and such that $f(\Sigma^*)$ is infinite?

Comment: How would you certify for the input that $L$ indeed contains a word of every length?

Comment: Every nonempty recursively enumerable language $L$ is the image of a polynomial-time function $f\colon\Sigma^*\to L$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Do you have a more detailed argument?

Comment: @Gamow I don't have an example right now but it probably should be possible to give a constructive proof with performance worse than polynomial

Comment: Fix $x_0\in L$, and a TM $M$ such that $M(x)$ halts iff $x\in L$. Define $f(w)$ as $x$ if $w$ is a sequence of configurations encoding a halting run of $M$ on an input $x$, and as $x_0$ if $w$ is not such a sequence.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If there is several such $x$ you take the shortest one? And the time complexity is at most quadratic right?

Comment: There can be only one $x$: the first configuration of the run of $M$ has $x$ on the input tape. Quadratic will do, but you can implement it even in linear time (on a multi-tape Turing machine).